# Unity - GameObject positioning at RayCast hit without clipping

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, virtual-reality, raycasting, clipping

So, I´m developing a VR game with base building functionalities and am using the position where the player hand Raycast hit as the position a preview GameObject has to go. But obviously when I do that, the gameObject clips through the Hit mesh. I am trying to find a way to avoid that.

I´ve came up with a solution but don´t get it to work in any way. Maybe it´s my idea, maybe my programming knowledge, no idea, but well. This would be it.

[image: artist's rendition]

So Preview GameObject Transform is set to the HitPoint transform and moved away from point of collision until not colliding anymore. I guess? I only come up with performance heavy solutions and they don´t even work anyways. Does someone know a good solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi There. Post what you have tried so far and where you are exactly stuck. Questions with code samples gain quicker attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you are looking for [`Physics.ComputePenetration`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.ComputePenetration.html)

> Compute the minimal translation required to separate the given colliders apart at specified poses.

So you will need a `Collider` on your placed object (the hit one already has one anyway) and then do e.g.

```c#
// Wherever you get this from
Collider objectToPlace;

if(Physics.Raycast(yourRay, out var hit))
{
    objectToPlace.trabsform.position = hit.point;

    if(Physics.ComputePenetration(objectToPlace, objectToPlace.transform.position, objectToPlace.transform.rotation, hit.collider, hit.transform.position, hit.transform.rotation, out var direction, out var distance))
    {
        objectToPlace.position += direction * distance;
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn´t test it until now, but it just was adding it, testing, and there we go, solved my issue just like that. Thank you a lot man! ComputePenetration was the one I needed!

Comment: I noticed that it doesn´t really work on non-convex mesh colliders, luckily that wouldn´t be too big of an issue but is there any way to make that work?